# Use Firebase Emulators as own pernament server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Can i use Firebase Emulators (`Firestore`, `Functions`) to serve them permanently on example VPS server?

Hosting + storage will be apache and from for example @angularfire I will call firestore and functions

Is this possible or i must pay for use functions :c

**#iAmPoor**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't say that it's *impossible* to use the emulator in this way, but I strongly recommend against it.  The emulator was only meant to be used during development and testing on your local machine before pushing code to production.  It's not meant to run persistently.  You could run into problems if you try to use it this way, since it's not tested to work like this.

You should know that Firebase and Google Cloud products have a free tier where you don't pay anything at all unless you exceed the free limits.  I suggest reviewing the [billing structure](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to find out what you actually get for free per month.  I think it's quite generous.

Comment: It's free if I run functions on node8, which *will be decommissioned on 2021-03-15*, and now functions demands pay-as-you-go plan, which means every firestore operation needs money - maybe not much but still even for small app I need to pay :/

Comment: It's free for node 10 as well.  You just need a credit card on file in can you exceed the free limit.  The limit hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said it is not verified to be used as such but I have tested an on-premises solution this way (no internet, about 100 IoT clients on LAN). Hosting server handles load well. The storage emulator works fine for small data sizes. The max time I know it ran without a problem is about 3 months.